# Place background image on bootstrap signin splash page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I am trying to customize Twitter Bootstrap's splash sign-in page.

I haven't touched the HTML, but I am trying to edit the background of the splash page.

Here is all the CSS I have added:

```
html {
  background: url("../img/bumpit_splash.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

What is happening is the top-half of the splash page retains its white background, but the bottom half gets the color of the background image I am trying to replace it with.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Use `body` instead. Here's a Bootstrap example: http://bootply.com/129025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without a preview, but i'm guessing your `<body>` tag has a white background, and because its a login form, its not as tall as the `<html>` tag(your viewport).

Disable the background color for `<body>`, or make it 100% tall and add the background this instead of the html element.

Comment: Yeah the `<body>` tag had a color, I made the `height: 100%;` and added the background info to it and everything works perfectly now. Thanks a ton!